# how to load data for all comboboxes one time in javascript?

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-easyui

```html
<code><li id="lisid" style="Display: none">
     <div id="divid" style="width:500px;">
     <table id="tableid">
     <tr>
 <td><table><tr><td><input id="rule_A" class="easyui-combobox" value="AV" style="width: 50px;"></td><td>rule_A</td></tr></table></td>
 <td><table><tr><td><input id="rule_B" class="easyui-combobox" value="BV" style="width: 50px;"></td><td>rule_B</td></tr></table></td>
 <td><table><tr><td><input id="rule_C" class="easyui-combobox" value="BV" style="width: 50px;"></td><td>rule_B</td></tr></table></td>
     </tr>

     </table></div></li></code>
```

I need to load it in js.these are not in rely on each other,but all the data of them are come from one table in the database.
how to load all the optiones of these three combobox in one ajax?

and when I wrote this:

```html
$('input[id^="rule_"]')
```

I can only get id = rule_A,why?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I have to say sorry, that this answer not directly as code as you used. But here is the concept that could help you.

As like what I have done using PHP and JQuery EasyUI

1. I pass all data from the table that I will using as Combobox into
   the page (view) as a variable. The data is the contain result of query. As an example in PHP `$text = "SELECT * FROM table A"; $d['data_a'] = $this->app_model->manualQuery($text);`, in this example I set data_a that I will pass to the view page with result of query. and don't forget to pass variable for the combobox value for this example I pass `$rule_A`, if the value is empty the set it with `$rule_A='';`
2. Check each data and filter which allowed to be list of the Combobox. For example in PHP I have `$data_a` then looping and filter for each Combobobox.

Example:

```
<select id="rule_A" class="easyui-combobox" style="width: 50px;">
   if (empty(rule_A)){
     <option value="">Select</option>
   }
   foreach ($data_a->result() as $dt){
     if('filter value that include as rule A'){
       if ($rule_A == $dt->id_or_something_key){
         <option value="$dt->id_or_something_key" selected="selected">$dt->name_or_description_of_rule;</option>
       }else{
         <option value="$dt->id_or_something_key">$dt->name_or_description_of_rule;</option>
       }
     }
   }
</select>
```

Hope that can help.